# C# API Cant get dynamic value to populate list

Tags: c#, json, api, c#-4.0, json.net

This program gets information from a database using API.  The JSON file comes in and populates content.  The content then populates the Dynamic "holder", however when I assign holder to "list" the data does not populate the list.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong with this.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Rootobject
        {
        //Employer and Carrier information 
        public string Employer { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string InsUnder { get; set; }
        public string Carrier { get; set; }
        public string CarrierPh { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string MailTo { get; set; }
        public string MailTo2 { get; set; }  //place holder
        public string MailTo3 { get; set; }
        public string EClaims { get; set; }
        public string FAXClaims { get; set; }
        public string DMOOption { get; set; }

    public class iapVm
    {
        public List<Rootobject> data { get; set; }
    }

    public static iapVm GetList(string iapNumber)
    {

        //Response object
        iapVm list = new iapVm();

        List<Rootobject> lstRootobject = new List<Rootobject>();

        //      //Create client object for request
        var client = new RestClient("http://myurls/json/"); /// call url

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        //      //Add parameter
        request.AddParameter("Number", Number);

        //      //Create response object
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var content = response.Content;

        //      //Convert string to json

        dynamic holder = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);



        holder = list;

        list.data = lstRootobject;

        return list; 
}
```

Comment: you're populating the "holder" and then you're not doing anything with and and override it to become "list". 

Then you interact with list directly.... But list is always just an empty `new iapVm()`

Comment: I'm not sure what is being returned by the `IRestResponse` but if it's the same as a `HttpClient` do you need to get the string out of content first?
e.g. `response.Content.ReadStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.
This still doesn't address any of the issues that you're not doing anything with holder and that list is always a default instance.

Comment: I'm just guessing now, cuz there's not much to go off... But maybe you want to delete the line `holder = list;` and then underneath `list.data = lstRootobject;` do a `list.data.Add(holder)`?

Comment: do you have a sample of the string that comes back in `content `

Comment: can you try this:
public static iapVm GetList(string iapNumber)
{
 iapVm list = new iapVm();
 var client = new RestClient("http://myurls/json/");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
 request.AddParameter("Number", Number);
 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 var content = response.Content;
 List<Rootobject> lstRootobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(content);
 list.data = lstRootobject;
 return list; 
}

Comment: I've posted my sample code that should be working, let me know if doing the same thing still works for you. I made sure that `Rootobject` and `iapVm` are seperate classes since theres no point for them to be nested. I'm deserializing the response directly into the list of `Rootobject` since theres no need to use a dynamic (dynamic is only dynamic for the developer, once you compile it's automatically generated and locked down).
p.s. I don't know if any of the data in your sample response is live, if it is you might want to edit it. (I tried to sanitize the version in my answer just incase)

Comment: 3am here so i'm gonna hit the sack, I hope you get it working, if not I'll check back in tomorrow and see if I can help... Or if somebody else beats me to it.
I think you're close but I think you should try to avoid using dynamic.
The issue might be since you are populating dynamic based on the json reply, then trying to re-assign it to list, that might cause the error you are seeing, but i don't think that's what you want to do. I think my answer is more accurately how you want to be doing this.
anyway, good luck. I hope it works.

Comment: Joe_DM - seems to populate list with values now, but my constructors aren't populating any data...is there a cast or something we can do ? or can you think of a reason it wouldn't be populating them based on this code?

Comment: I don't see any constructors in this code?
Deserializing JSON will only populate properties and won't invoke any constructors?
I don't understand the question sorry. :(

Comment: Since `RootObject` is inside of a list and `iapVm.data` is a list, there could be multiple values for `RootObject` inside of the list... e.g. if you call `iapVm.data.FirstOrDefault()` do you see anything?

In my test setup, this is what it looks like for me:
http://imgur.com/a/T7cMC

Comment: It's hard to tell if this is a copy/paste error, but in your code is the class `iapVm` nested inside of the class `Rootobject`? I don't think it should be and suspect it's just a paste error, but if it is, maybe that's an issue?

For example, in my sample answer there are three separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a quick test using the sample Json data you provided and it seems to work okay by deserializing the response content directly into a `List<RootObject>`

Heres what my test looks like: (I cut out all the web call stuff since I can't test it and we know you are getting the content back okay.)

```
 public class Rootobject
 {
     //Employer and Carrier information 
     public string Employer { get; set; }
     public string Phone { get; set; }
     public string InsUnder { get; set; }
     public string Carrier { get; set; }
     public string CarrierPh { get; set; }
     public string Group { get; set; }
     public string MailTo { get; set; }
     public string MailTo2 { get; set; } //place holder
     public string MailTo3 { get; set; }
     public string EClaims { get; set; }
     public string FAXClaims { get; set; }
     public string DMOOption { get; set; }
 }

 public class iapVm
 {
     public List<Rootobject> data { get; set; }
 }

 public class Class1
 {
     public iapVm TestDeserializingValidResponseContent()
     {
         //Response object
         iapVm list = new iapVm();
         string content = "[{\"_id\":\"asdf\",\"Employer\":\"1 800 Foo & Bar (Schedule Plan)\",\"EmpNumberXXX\":\"(333)-111-2222 : (800)-234-2344\",\"InsUnder\":\"asdf asdf\",\"DMOOption\":\"No\",\"Medical\":\"asdf (800)-234-2344 Group#:23443\",\"DateXXX\":\"May\",\"Carrier\":\"Cigna\",\"‌​CarrierPh\":\"(222)-‌​234-234234\",\"FAXClai‌​ms\":\"No. Will Not Accept\",\"Plan\":\"Self-Funded\",\"Group\":\"Cigna (800)-234-2344 Group#:23443\",\"GroupNum\":\"2343\",\"EClaims\":\"Yes\"}]";
         List<Rootobject> lstRootobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Rootobject>>(content);
         list.data = lstRootobject;
         return list;
     }
 }
```

Comment: awesome, I'm glad you got it working :) I know how stressful these things can get sometime, We've all been there